# malloc pointer cause memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I have following code, will this cause memory leak, after function returns, there are many mallocated memory, not claimed?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test
{
    char * name;
    char * value;
};

void test_ok()
{
   int i;
   struct test * ok;

   for (i=0;i<10000;i++)
   {
       ok =malloc(sizeof(struct test));
   } 

}
void main ()
{
    int j=0;
    while(j<60)  
    {
      test_ok();
      j++;
      sleep(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: `test_ok` is not called....

Comment: Your code is not doing anything but wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: oops, just added function call.

Comment: Seems you already know the answer. Yes of course it will create massive memory leaks.

Comment: What makes you thing your program doesn't create memory leaks ?? You are allocating tons of memory without ever freeing it.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `test_ok()` is never called, so the `malloc()` is never executed. So no memory allocation happens, no question of memory leak there.

Any decent compiler will optimize away the `test_ok()` code, anyway.

---

EDIT:

If you actually make a call to `test_ok()` from the `main()`, it will eventually call the function, allocate the memory via calling `malloc()` [provided malloc is success] and do nothing. So, theoretically, yes, you'll have memory leaks there, plenty.

Point to note: As you mentioned,

> [...] after function returns [...]

assuming you're talking about `test_ok()` function, no, simply returning from a function with a malloc-ed pointer does not cause memory leak. A leak happens when you **miss** to release the memory after the usage is done (no referenced/used anymore).

When exiting the program, returning from `main()`, all the allocated memories will be de-allocated anyways. The problem due to memory leak appears when a program keeps on running.

That said, as per the latest standards, `void main()` is not a valid signature for hosted environments, you should use `int main(void)`, at least.

Answer (score 2):

You program doesn't call `test_ok()`, so the answer is no.

Had `test_ok()` be called, the answer would have been yes. You are allocating memory on the heap using `malloc` and not cleaning it up afterwards with `free`.

**EDIT:** Now the OP has been edited to call `test_ok()`, so yes, this program would leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you actually call `test_ok()` from within `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Before reassigning the pointer, you should free it. Otherwise the previously allocated memory is no longer pointed by anything (but still allocated), therefore leaked.